# How to replace scipy.spatial.distance with np.linalg.norm in Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am following this tutorial to implement object tracking for my project - https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/07/23/simple-object-tracking-with-opencv/

Method is to find centroids of detected objects in the initial frame, and then calculate the shortest distance to the other centroids of detected objects that show up on the next frame. Assumption is that a centroid that is closest would be a same object.

In the tutorial -

```
from scipy.spatial import distance as dist
...
D = dist.cdist(np.array(objectCentroids), newCentroids)
```

is used to calculate the distance (Euclidean Distance). Unfortunately, I cannot use scipy module as I am trying to deploy this to AWS Lambda (size limit). In this case, the recommendation is to use this - https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html

```
D = np.linalg.norm(objectCentroids – newCentroids)
```

The issue with this is that, unlike `dist.cdist`, where it computes all and any matrix, `np.linalg.norm` only outputs 1 value, which is calculated after newCentroids is subtracted from objectCentroids matrix. I am about to loop over n times (however big the matrix is) and append to another matrix to construct the result I need. However, I wasn't sure if my understanding of this concept is correct or not, so I wanted to seek out some help. If anyone knows of a better way, I would appreciate any pointer.

**UPDATE**

Based on the feedback/answer I got, I updated the code a bit, and well... it seems to be working -

```
n = arrayObjectCentroids.shape[0]
m = inputCentroids.shape[0]

T = []

for i in range(0,n):
    for z in range(0,m):
        Tv = np.linalg.norm(arrayObjectCentroids[i] - inputCentroids[z])
        # print(f'Tv is \n {Tv}')
        T = np.append(T, Tv)
        # print(f'T is \n {T}')
    print(f'new T is \n {T}')   
D = np.reshape(T, (n, m))
print(f'D is \n {D}')
```

In this case, if there is one object and moving a little -

newCentroids is `[[224  86]]`, and the shape of it is (1, 2)...
objectCentroids is `[[224  86]]`, and the shape objectCentroids is (1, 2)

D is`[[0.]]`

If I have 3 objects, -

new Centroids is

```
 [[228  79]
 [ 45 127]
 [103 123]]
```

shape of inputCentroids is (3, 2)

objectCentroids is

```
 [[228  79]
 [ 45 127]
 [103 123]]
```

shape objectCentroids is (3, 2)

D is

```
 [[  0.         189.19038031 132.51792332]
 [189.19038031   0.          58.13776741]
 [132.51792332  58.13776741   0.        ]]
```

Great that it works, but I feel like this may not be the best solution out there, and if you have any pointer, I would appreciate it!
Thanks!

Comment: What are the shapes of `objectCentroids` and `newCentroids`?

Comment: @Dion Shape changes depending on how many objects is detected. But it goes like this. If 1 object, objectCentroids is [[264 110]] (so 1 x 2).  inputCentorids is another point in the next frame, so if still 1 object it will stay as 1 x 2. In this case I use scipy's `cdist`, the output is (1 x 1); however, if i use `np.linalg.norm`, my output is 1 value as stated below by DrBwts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** Edited code to address comments below

If in your case you have vectors in Euclidean space then `np.linalg.norm` will return the length of that vector.

So `objectCentroid – newCentroid`  will give you the vector between the point at `objectCentroid` and the point at `newCentroid`. Note that is between 2 points and not an array containing ALL points.

To get all combinations of points I've used `itertools` & then reshaped the array to give the same output as `dist`

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import distance as dist
import itertools

# Example data
objectCentroids = np.array([[0,0,0],[1,1,1],[2,2,2], [3,3,3]])
newCentroids    = np.array([[4,4,4],[5,5,5],[6,6,6],[7,7,7]])
comb            = list(itertools.product(objectCentroids, newCentroids))
all_dist        = [] 

for pair in comb:

    dis = np.linalg.norm((pair[0] - pair[1]))
    all_dist.append(dis)

all_dist = np.reshape(all_dist, (len(objectCentroids), len(objectCentroids)))
D        = dist.cdist(objectCentroids, newCentroids)   

print(D)
print(" ")
print(all_dist)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response and explanation. Unfortunately, the output it gives isn't enough. Above method will result in (1 x 3) matrix output, but what I am looking for is the same shape and values as `D = dist.cdist(np.array(objectCentroids), newCentroids)` which in this case should be ( 3 x 3) matrix.

Comment: I am looking for the same output because after i get those values, I further process it to find shortest distances of all points. By doing this - `rows = D.min(axis=1).argsort()` then `cols = D.argmin(axis=1)[rows]`     When I say I... I mean that is what the blog was doing

Comment: @a428tm I have changed the code to give you the output you are after.

Comment: Thank you so much! This seems to be running well and might be more efficient than the solution I updated. Thank you again!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Numpy broadcasting to create a distance matrix.

Read about it [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) and [here](https://scipy.github.io/old-wiki/pages/EricsBroadcastingDoc).

The basic idea is:

Stack (reshape) your centroids as `(1, n, 3)` and `(n, 1, 3)` where the last dimension with shape 3 is `(x,y,z)`. Then subtract the arrays and use `np.linalg.norm` to calculate the distance along axis ... hm ... probably the last one. That should yield a square `(n,n)` distance matrix.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am not sure if I understand what you mean... Would you mind if I ask you with a real number? If newCentroids is [[243  76], [ 94 134], [ 22 145]] and objectCentroids is [[243 77], [94 134], [22 145]] and `D = dist.cdist(np.array(objectCentroids), newCentroids)` returns  [[  1.         159.53056134 231.22499865], [159.89058759   0.          72.83543094], [231.52105736  72.83543094   0.        ]]    Would broadcasting to correct dimension and running `np.linalg.norm` output the correct answer? Was that what you explained? Or Did i get that wrong completely?

Comment: If they shape of the array is different (elements in objectCentroids and newCentroids) then you will get a (m,n) array.

Comment: The idea is to calculate all possible distances, every point to every other one. That's the square matrix as returned by https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html